# Get duplicated by date

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>  ID          Start      
> 0001       31JAN2015      
> 0001       31JAN2015       
> 0003       16FEB2016      
> 0006       01FEB2018
> 0004       31DEC2016 
> 0004       31DEC2016
> ```

is there a way to retrieve which ID has identical Start date, i.e. is duplicated?

Desired output:

> ```
>  ID          Start      
> 0001       31JAN2015      
> 0001       31JAN2015  
> 0004       31DEC2016 
> 0004       31DEC2016
> ```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Look at the documentation for `PROC SORT DUPOUT=`

Comment: Why Id=0001 came twice in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `proc sort` to remove duplicates and create a list of IDs with duplicates.

```
proc sort data=have nodupkey dupout=dupes;
    by date;
run;
```

In your example, ID 4 does not have a duplicate start date although the start day itself is the same (31st).